# Let $F$ be a field with four elements $F = \{0,1,a,b\}$. What is $a^2 + a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> Let $F$ be a field with four elements $F = \{0,1,a,b\}$. What is $a^2 + a$?

I proved that $a\cdot b = 1$ by eliminating other possibilities.

I used $a\cdot b = 1$ to prove that $a\cdot a = b$.

So $a^2 + a = b + a$

I tried prooving that $b + a = 1$ by elimination and I derived a contradiction for $b + a =a$ and $b+a = b$ but I don't know how to disprove $b+a=0$.

Also I am not sure how to prove other additions in the addition table such as $1 +1, a + 1, a+ a$

Comment: $F_4$ has characteristic $2$ (why??) try and prove it, and this should help you with the final lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $b+a = 0$. Multiplication with $a$ gives $1+b = 0$. Multiplication with $b$ gives $a+1 = 0$. Hence, both $a$ and $b$ are the additive inverse of $1$. A contradiction.

Comment: At the end, can we write $1 + b = a + 1$ and subtract $1$ instead of explaining it in words?

Comment: You can do that, too. Sure. You also can write $b = -1 = a$.

Comment: The multiplication by $a$ is enough:  As soon as you have $b+a=0$ and $1+b=0$, you have the contradiction $a=1$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Well observed. Tumbs up!

Comment: @amsmath Is there a similar way to disprove 1 + 1 = b? I couldn't find a way to get a contradiction.

Comment: @lakada If $1+1=b$, then $a+a = ab = 1$. Adding $b$ gives $1+a = 1+ b$ and thus $a=b$, which is a contradiction. Similarly, one proves $1+1\neq a$. Since $1+1=1$ is complete bullshit, we must have that $1+1=0$.

Answer (score 4):

$F^\times = \{1,a,b\}$ has order $3$ and so is cyclic. Therefore, $b=a^2$ and $a^2 + a = b + a$.

Now, $a^2+a=0 \implies a^2=-a \implies a^4=a^2 \implies b=a^2=1$, which contradicts $b\ne1$.

Comment: Or, along these lines - since $F^*$ has order 3, then $a^3 = 1$ so $(a-1)(a^2+a+1) = 0$ but $a \ne 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: what is the characteristic of $F$?  What does that mean regarding $a+a$?